# Noindex, nofollow with meta-tags Ruby gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-tags

I'm using the [meta-tags](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags#metatags-usage) gem, and trying to add noindex and nofollow meta tags to my view.

In the HAML view file, I have:

```
- noindex_meta_tag
- content_for :head do
  - display_meta_tags noindex: true, nofollow: true
```

In `application_helper.rb`, I have:

```
def noindex_meta_tag
  set_meta_tags noindex: true
  set_meta_tags nofollow: true
end
```

I've tried many variations of this based on the documentation I linked to above, but still can't get it to work.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is another part of my app the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps need to output the result using the = operator, rather than - in HAML:

```
= display_meta_tags noindex: true, nofollow: true
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. The `- content_for :head do` was also causing problems. I'm still looking into that.